# how to wire the hibernate session factory manually in spring config

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I have the hibernate-context

```
<context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/spring.properties" />

    <!-- Enable annotation style of managing transactions -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />   

    <!-- Declare the Hibernate SessionFactory for retrieving Hibernate sessions -->
    <!-- See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/annotation/AnnotationSessionFactoryBean.html -->                           
    <!-- See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/index.html?org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html -->
    <!-- See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/index.html?org/hibernate/Session.html -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"
                 p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
                 p:configLocation="${hibernate.config}"
                 p:packagesToScan="com.vaannila"/>

    <!-- Declare a datasource that has pooling capabilities-->   
    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
                destroy-method="close"
                p:driverClass="${app.jdbc.driverClassName}"
                p:jdbcUrl="${app.jdbc.url}"
                p:user="${app.jdbc.username}"
                p:password="${app.jdbc.password}"
                p:acquireIncrement="5"
                p:idleConnectionTestPeriod="60"
                p:maxPoolSize="100"
                p:maxStatements="50"
                p:minPoolSize="10" />

    <!-- Declare a transaction manager-->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager" 
                p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />

</beans>
```

now i want to pass sessionFactory in my constructor of DAO like below

```
<bean id="registrationDAO" class="com.vaannila.dao.RegistrationDAOimpl" >
     <constructor-arg ref="sessionFactory"/>
     </bean>
```

but error says that bean sessionfactory not found

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'registrationDAO' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'sessionFactory' is defined
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)

Comment: I'm sure the error says more than that. What else does it say?

Comment: i think it was obvious as sessionfactory is defined in different xml file while DAO is in applicationContext , but i have added tat error

Answer (score 2):

This work for me

```
<bean id="hibernateSessionFactory"
                class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource">
        </property>
</bean>


<bean id="hibernateTransactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernateSessionFactory" />
</bean>


<bean class="com.vaannila.dao.RegistrationDAOimpl"
        id="registrationDAO">
        <property name="sessionFactory">
            <ref bean="hibernateSessionFactory" />
        </property>
</bean>
```